# How to configure pyftpdlib to create an 'active' only FTP server?

Tags: python, ftp

I need to create a test case for a FTP client that involves connecting to a server that only accepts 'active' FTP connections. For other cases I am using pyftpdlib, and it works like charm, but I can't see an easy way to configure it to behave just in FTP active mode, and not passive.

Thanks.

Comment: There is an ActiveDTP class in the source tree... that might be a place to start, but I haven't fully grok'd how to use DTPHandlers

Answer (score 1):

If by what you wrote in the title you mean "literaly disable PASV (passive)" mode you can just tell pyftpdlib to not interpret that command. Not tested:

```
from pyftpdlib.ftpserver import FTPHandler
handler = FTPHandler
del handler.proto_cmds['PASV']
del handler.proto_cmds['EPSV']
...
```

This way pyftpdlib will reject any PASV/EPSV request with "550 Command PASV not understood.".